# Triple integral over cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Compute $$\iiint_D (x^2+y^2) \, dxdydz, \, D=\{(x,y,z); 0 \leq x^2 +y^2 \leq z^2, \, 0 \leq z\leq 1 \}$$**

I wish to compute this as $$ \int_0^{1} \left(\iint_E f(x,y) dx dy\right) dz $$ where $x \rightarrow r \cos \theta, y \rightarrow r \sin \theta$. The functional determinant for this mapping is $r$ and we get $$\iint_E r(r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta) dr d \theta, \, E=\{(r, \theta); \, 0 \leq r \leq 1, \, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}$$
the value of this integral is $\pi/2$. The triple integral is the integrand, which is $\pi/2$ times the length of the interval, which is 1, so we get $\pi/2$ as the value of the triple integral. However, this is **entirely wrong**. The actual value of the integral is $\pi/10$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your $E$ should be 
$$E=\{(r, \theta); \, 0 \leq r \leq z, \, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}$$

Remember the inequality $0\leq x^2+y^2\leq z^2$. This gives you an upper bound for $r$.

Comment: I understand. So now I have instead integrated over a cylinder with the radius/height 1?

Comment: @Lozansky: Yes, yours was a cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

$$
I=\int_0^1 dz \int_{x^2+y^2\le z^2} dxdy (x^2+y^2)
$$
$$
I=\int_0^1 dz \int_0^z rdr\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r^2
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_0^1 dz \int_0^z r^3dr 
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_0^1 dz \frac{z^4}{4} =\frac{\pi}{10}.
$$